# CustomPicker Ok and Cancel buttons' color

Tags: xamarin.forms, colors, picker, custom-renderer

I have this custompicker class in android project:

```
 public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        private Context context;
        private IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
        private AlertDialog _dialog;

        public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;
            Control.Click += Control_Click1;
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Control.Click -= Control_Click1;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void Control_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker model = Element;

            var picker = new NumberPicker(Context);
            if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
            {
                picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
                picker.MinValue = 0;
                picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
                picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
                picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
                picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
            }

            var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            layout.AddView(picker);

            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
            builder.SetView(layout);
            builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");

            //change the text or color here
            builder.SetNegativeButton(Html.FromHtml("<font color='#039BE5'>Cancel</font>"), (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
                _dialog = null;
            });

             //change the text or color here
            builder.SetPositiveButton(Html.FromHtml("<font color='#039BE5'>OK</font>"), (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
                // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                        Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                    // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                    // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                    Control?.ClearFocus();
                }
                _dialog = null;
            });

            _dialog = builder.Create();
            _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
            {
                ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            };
            _dialog.Show();
        }
    }
```

I tried running my project on my phone Xiaomi POCOPHONE F1 (Android 9) and 2 emulators (Android 8.1) and the colors of cancel and ok buttons are designed Perfectly. But when I tried running the project on Huawei PLE-701L and SAMSUNG SM-T365 (Android 5.1) the color of the buttons didn't changed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question is answered here:  [Picker button's color not changing on android 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540894/picker-buttons-color-not-changing-on-android-5-1/56557976#56557976)

I added the styles code in the correct answer in the link, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Get the button object through the API of dialog and set the text color of the button. This method can be personalized. One point needs to be noted: it must be called after `show`

in your custom renderer,below  `_dialog.Show();`

```
....
_dialog.Show();
Button btnOk = _dialog.GetButton((int)DialogInterface.ButtonPositive);
btnOk .SetTextColor(Color.Red);
Button btnCancel= _dialog.GetButton((int)DialogInterface.ButtonNegative);
btnCancel.SetTextColor(Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style in style.xml

```
<style name="SpinnerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#ff00ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff00ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffff00</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

you can change allthe color including buttons.

and you can also use

```
 <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#1e87f0</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#1e87f0</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#1e87f0</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Ok cool, can you help me how to link this style to the picker?

Comment: @mohammadanouti just copy the code and paste it in Resource/Values/style.xml file inside android project

Comment: Yes I did that and nothing changed, that's why I asked I thought I'm missing something!