# Picker button's color not changing on android 5.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-styles, picker

I was searching for a way to change the colors of the ok and cancel button of my custom picker. I added this code to the styles file on the android project:

```
<style name="SpinnerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#039BE5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#039BE5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#039BE5</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#039BE5</item>
  </style>
```

I run the app on my Xiaomi POCOPHONE F1 (Android v9) and on 2 emulators (Android v8.1) the color changed and everything worked fine, I tried deploying the app on my tablets (Android v5.1) the colors didn't change!!

Am I missing something?

Comment: sadly not yet :/

Comment: have you try the method in your another post ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476142/custompicker-ok-and-cancel-buttons-color. they both worked for me- -

Comment: Yes, I tried it. My target Android version is 8.1 and when switching to 5.1 it is giving me errors that I'm still trying to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use style for the dialog ,you could try this:

in your theme style:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/SpinnerDialog</item>
```

then custom dialog style:

```
<style name="SpinnerDialog"
     parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="android:colorAccent">#039BE5</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the settings of your android version / SDK. Maybe you have set a too high version, so the app doesn't work on devices that have a lower android version than your own pocophone.

You can change the settings under your Android project properties -> Application, set the Target Android Version and Compile using Android Version to API Level (of your tablet) to fix it.

Comment: I lower the android version to 5.0, it gives me an error on the Xamarin.Android.Support NuGet packages that are not compatible with monoandroid50. Does it mean that I need to downgrade them to be compatible? and how I know the compatible version for them?

Comment: maybe try to rebuild your app?

Comment: Of course, I tried to clean and rebuild it  and the same errors stays