# How *dynamically* change EVERY color iOS/Android? E.g. in Droid code, override "colorAccent" in "Styles.xml"

Tags: xamarin.forms, themes

I am adding color themes to a Xamarin Forms app.
The theme is spec'ed to **change dynamically** depending on which **client's location** the user is standing at/near. We have both "light" and "dark" themed clients, having a variety of color palettes; so it needs to be possible to change all colors of **all** display items. Dynamically.

**So far, my dynamic theming works for *almost* all types of views.**

I'm **stuck on two details** when coloring the iOS-style (vertical scrolling wheel) `Xamarin.Forms.Picker` on Android:

**Question 1:** How change the background color?
**Question 2:** How change the "Cancel" button's text color?

This Android `NumberPicker`-based XF View, doesn't seem to be fully color-customizable out of the box. As of latest XF, 4.3.0.991211.

---

**----- What I've tried:-----**

---

A. Set Android theme colors *statically*, in `Style.xml` resource file. Success. But its static.

---

B. Download [Xamarin Forms Light/Dark Theme Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-theming/).

Build and run on Android. Go to its "Select Theme" picker. Pick light theme. Go to picker again - white background, so far, so good. Pick dark theme. Go to picker again - the picker is still black-on-white. No solution here.

---

C. Found online how to dynamically change `AlertDialog`s "OK"/"Cancel" button text colors, using an AlertDialog "builder", and getting at the resource IDs. Successfully implemented that. Not sure how to apply the same technique to Picker.

**Question 3:** How discover what resource IDs are used in the Android Control used by XF Picker?

---

D. Clone Xamarin Forms source code. Copy Droid PickerRenderer into my code. Most of the code can't be run because it depends on `internal` classes/functions. Make mine inherit from the built-in one, and comment out any code that isn't needed / won't compile.

Customize `OnElementChanged`, because that is where `TextColor` is set.

In the custom renderer source code, `IPickerRenderer.OnClick()` builds an `AlertDialog` containing a `NumberPicker`. I don't see any logic that sets Background color or "Cancel" button's text color. But at least we have known Android classes. *See Question 3 above.*

---

E. At a minimum, **[having a small number of predefined themes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28033500/199364)** might be a solution. Or [Android theme.ApplyStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905131/199364) - but can this be a *dynamic* style? I haven't yet tested to see if either of these successfully changes the details that I am stuck on. [Will report back after I try.]

---

F. It might be possible by **restarting the app** to change theme: [any-color themes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48517223/199364). This would be my last resort; first seeing if I can control colors completely from within C#, without a restart.

---

NOTE: There are many posts at SO and Xamarin.Forums that talk *generally* about theming in Xamarin Forms. I'm past that point, so I won't list those here, except to mention [Clint St.Laurent's theming post](https://redpillxamarin.com/2018/07/19/2018-104-resources-styles-and-themes/), which (taking a quick glance at it) looks similar to what I've done. *All I have left are a small number of tiny details - which Xamarin Forms fails to apply theme colors to, in my testing.*

---

G. Other SO posts that seem related - but don't do the exact tasks listed in Questions 1 & 2:

[Picker implemented as an AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56421729/199364). Shows a custom PickerRenderer. But doesn't show how to set the colors in Q 1 & 2.

Another [Picker implemented as an AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56476142/199364). Likewise.

[How to really change primary and accent color in android lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25815769/199364) - I mention answers from this in `E` and `F`. If I can't achieve the result via C# code in custom PickerRenderer, I will investigate these.

---

Xamarin Forums posts:

[How to change the colorAccent at runtime?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98614/is-it-possible-to-change-the-coloraccent-at-runtime). The only answer given doesn't change theme's `colorAccent`. It just changes the app bar's color.

---

**CLARIFICATION:** There are plenty of doc, forum, and blog posts that describe the *general* mechanism of Xamarin Forms theming. Not looking for answers to that. I'm just looking to resolve *a small number of missing details*, as of latest stable Xamarin Forms, 4.3.0.991211. **Hopefully the day will come when Xamarin Forms successfully themes 100% of the details of all types of controls - at which time this Question and Answer will be obsolete.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation of `D.` in the question. Credits given as comments in the code.

This **custom Android PickerRenderer** dynamically sets 3 colors: text (blue), background behind the "wheel" of texts (light orange), buttons (dark red).

[image: Picker with dynamic blue text, light-orange background, dark red accent color.]

Clarification: the *static* Android theme has a dark background. The goal is to dynamically change from that dark theme to a light theme. To make it very obvious what colors have been successfully set, strongly tinted colors are used.

The white "dividers" between the texts I haven't colored yet. I've seen mention in either Xamarin or Android docs of a divider drawable. It should be straightforward to get hold of that, and set its color. **EDIT**: *Maybe* `titleDivider` in Tiago Flores code snippet in [Change picker control pop-up background and text colors](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48987/can-we-change-the-picker-control-pop-up-background-and-text-color), or in [Vahid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439849/199364). OR `selectionDividerField` in [Tapa Save's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883356/199364).

NOTE: I haven't added a custom XF property to control the button color; hard-coded to `Color.Accent`.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Text.Style;
using Java.Lang;

// PickerEditText
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using AColor = Android.Graphics.Color;
using Picker = Xamarin.Forms.Picker;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(LCPickerRenderer))]
namespace Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
{
    // Based on Xamarin.Forms source code, modified.
    public class LCPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer, IPickerRenderer   //ViewRenderer<Picker, EditText>, IPickerRenderer
    {
        AlertDialog _dialog;
        NumberPicker _picker;

        public LCPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            //AutoPackage = false;
        }

        [Obsolete("This constructor is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use PickerRenderer(Context) instead.")]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public LCPickerRenderer()
        {
            //AutoPackage = false;
        }

        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            if (e.OldElement != null) {
                //((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldElement.Items).CollectionChanged -= RowsCollectionChanged;
            }

            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                // --- custom work ---
                if (Control != null) {
                    SetTextColor();
                    SetBackgroundColor();
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == Picker.BackgroundColorProperty.PropertyName) {
                SetBackgroundColor();
            } else if (e.PropertyName == Picker.TextColorProperty.PropertyName) {
                SetTextColor();
            }

            //if (e.PropertyName == Picker.TitleProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Picker.TitleColorProperty.PropertyName)
            //    UpdatePicker();
            //else if (e.PropertyName == Picker.SelectedIndexProperty.PropertyName)
            //    UpdatePicker();
            //else if (e.PropertyName == Picker.CharacterSpacingProperty.PropertyName)
            //    UpdateCharacterSpacing();
            //else if (e.PropertyName == Picker.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)
            //    UpdateTextColor();
            //else if (e.PropertyName == Picker.FontAttributesProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Picker.FontFamilyProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Picker.FontSizeProperty.PropertyName)
            //    UpdateFont();
        }


        void IPickerRenderer.OnClick()
        {
            Picker model = Element;

            if (_dialog != null)
                return;

            var xfTextColor = Element.TextColor;
            _picker = new NumberPicker(Context);
            if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any()) {
                _picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
                _picker.MinValue = 0;
                _picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
                _picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
                _picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
                _picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
            }

            var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            layout.AddView(_picker);

            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);

            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
            builder.SetView(layout);

            if (!Element.IsSet(Picker.TitleColorProperty)) {
                builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
            } else {
                var title = new SpannableString(model.Title ?? "");
                title.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(model.TitleColor.ToAndroid()), 0, title.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);

                builder.SetTitle(title);
            }

            // TODO: get texts (and whether to show) from XF Element.
            builder.SetNegativeButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel, (s, a) => {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
                _dialog = null;
            });
            builder.SetPositiveButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Ok, (s, a) => {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, _picker.Value);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged. 
                // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
                if (Element != null) {
                    if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                        Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
                }
                _dialog = null;
            });

            _dialog = builder.Create();
            _dialog.DismissEvent += (sender, args) => {
                ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
                _dialog?.Dispose();
                _dialog = null;
            };
            _dialog.Show();

            // TODO: Control this via a custom XF property.
            var buttonColor = Color.Accent.ToAndroid();
            // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555965/199364.
            var btnCancel = _dialog.GetButton((int)DialogInterface.ButtonNegative);
            // "?" in case no such button was attached.
            btnCancel?.SetTextColor(buttonColor);
            var btnOK = _dialog.GetButton((int)DialogInterface.ButtonPositive);
            btnOK?.SetTextColor(buttonColor);

            SetTextColor();
            SetBackgroundColor();
        }

        private void SetTextColor()
        {
            Control?.SetTextColor(Element.TextColor.ToAndroid());
            if (_picker != null)
                SetTextColor(_picker, Element.TextColor.ToAndroid());
        }

        private void SetBackgroundColor()
        {
            Control?.SetBackgroundColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            _picker?.SetBackgroundColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            _dialog?.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new global::Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid()));
        }

        // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657169/199364
        // TODO: When support API 29, this needs to be modified re https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883356/199364 ?
        public static bool SetTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker, AColor color)
        {
            var sdkInt = global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt;
            //var limitSdk = global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q;

            int count = numberPicker.ChildCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var child = numberPicker.GetChildAt(i);
                if (child.GetType() == typeof(EditText)) {
                    try {
                        var selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.Class
                                                                    .GetDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                        selectorWheelPaintField.Accessible = true;

                        EditText editText = (EditText)child;
                        editText.SetTextColor(color);

                        var paint = (global::Android.Graphics.Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.Get(numberPicker);
                        paint.Color = color;

                        numberPicker.Invalidate();
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        Log.Warn("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                    }
                    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        Log.Warn("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Log.Warn("setNumberPickerTextColor", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**BONUS: Style an Android AlertDialog:**

[image: AlertDialog with different colors for title, message, each button, background]

Most dialogs can be built on Android (in your Android project code) using AlertDialog.Builder. This can be done *without* making a custom Renderer. In this code, I use variously named colors from my XF Application's Resources. Google techniques for color theming in Xamarin Form, to see how to set such resources to different color values:

```
// Extracted from a larger class. Some of these not used in the code here.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

// For Extension: color.ToAndroid.
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

public static partial class UI
{

    // If cancelHandler is null, no Cancel button will be added.
    // If noHandler is not null, then "OK" is renamed "Yes".
    public static void ShowAlertDialog(string title, string message,
                                        EventHandler okHandler, EventHandler cancelHandler,
                                        EventHandler noHandler = null, bool textIsYes = false)
    {
        bool hasCancel = (cancelHandler != null);
        bool hasNo = (noHandler != null);
        string okOrYes = PS.LocalizedString((textIsYes || hasNo ? "Yes" : "OK"));
        // When both cancel and no, is "Cancel".
        // When neither cancel or no, defaults to "Cancel", which does nothing.
        // The only time this is "No", is if there is a No button, but no Cancel button.
        string cancelOrNo = PS.LocalizedString((hasNo && !hasCancel ? "No" : "Cancel"));
        EventHandler cancelOrNoHandler = (hasCancel ? cancelHandler : noHandler);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.it);

        var titleOb = new Android.Text.SpannableString(title);
        // TODO: Add custom XF property to set this.
        var titleColor = (Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["MaxForegroundColor"];
        titleOb.SetSpan(new Android.Text.Style.ForegroundColorSpan(titleColor.ToAndroid()), 0, title.Length, Android.Text.SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
        builder.SetTitle(titleOb);

        builder.SetMessage(message);

        if (hasCancel || hasNo) {
            builder.SetNegativeButton(cancelOrNo,
                                 (s, e) => {
                                     cancelOrNoHandler?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                                 });
        }

        // Only used when BOTH Cancel and No buttons.
        if (hasNo && hasCancel)
            builder.SetNeutralButton(PS.LocalizedString("No"),
                                (s, e) => { noHandler.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty); });

        builder.SetPositiveButton(okOrYes, (s, e) => {
            if (okHandler != null)
                okHandler.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.Show();
        SetAlertStyle(dialog);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This doesn't set Title Color. Set that earlier, while building the dialog.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialog"></param>
    private static void SetAlertStyle(AlertDialog dialog)
    {
        // Use these if succeed in changing both title and background colors.
        var foreColor = (Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["ForegroundColor"];
        var accentAgainstBack = (Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["AccentSaturated25Fore33"];

        var backColor = (Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"];
        SetBackgroundColor(dialog, backColor);

        //// DIDN'T WORK: No effect on title color. Set earlier, while building the dialog.
        //int alertViewId = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
        //SetItemTextColor(dialog, "alertTitle", accentAgainstBack);

        SetItemTextColor(dialog, "message", foreColor);

        SetItemTextColor(dialog, "button1", (Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["AccentSaturated25Fore33"]);
        SetItemTextColor(dialog, "button2", (Xamarin.Forms.Color)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["ForegroundColor"]);
    }

    private static void SetItemTextColor(AlertDialog dialog, string itemResourceName, Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
    {
        int textId = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier(itemResourceName, "id", "android");
        TextView text = dialog.FindViewById<TextView>(textId);
        text?.SetTextColor(color.ToAndroid());
    }

    private static void SetBackgroundColor(AlertDialog dialog, Xamarin.Forms.Color xfColor)
    {
        dialog?.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new global::Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable(xfColor.ToAndroid()));
    }

}
```